# Can a linq query EVER change its data source, i.e. a dictionary's content?

Tags: c#, linq

It seems to me that Linq can only -query- a given data source, that is, it browses through it and returns stuff from it as necessary, but doesn't change anything. However, the wording in some of the answers I found on the matter are making me doubt this understanding. Is my understanding correct in all circumstances? Can a linq query -ever- change the content of the data source it is associated to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can a linq query -ever- change the content of the data source it is associated to?

Yes, though this is a bad idea.

LINQ queries (at least with LINQ to Objects) work by using delegates for the filter or mapping operations.  In general, these shouldn't ever cause side effects, but that doesn't mean that they *couldn't* do so if you forced them to.  The actual LINQ methods won't change the data, but they work via delegates that are just code you provide, which means that code could do anything.

Note that this would, in general, be a bad idea.

For example, say you were doing a query over a collection of `Person` instances:

```
var results = people.Where(p => p.Name == "Foo")
                    .Select(p =>
                            {
                               // This is evil, don't do it!
                               p.Name = "Bar";
                               return p;
                            });
```

That being said, this is unlikely to work with LINQ against an `IQueryable<T>`.  In that case, the lambda you provide will be converted into an `Expression`, which will in turn need to be translated by the provider into some other form (ie: Entity Framework converts this to SQL).  As such, you would only be able to create side effects if the provider was written in a way that this would translate into a meaningful form, which is unlikely to be the case.

Comment: Thank you Reed. I must wait another 6 minutes apparently before I can accept the answer but yours is already perfectly adequate. Interestingly, I actually asked because I wanted to make sure that the query -does not- change the data source, as a form of security. It's now clear that the query -can- change the source and that's a problem. Stand-by for a question specifically on how to avoid it. =)

Comment: @manu3D with LINQ to Objects, anything is fair game.  With LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework, etc, you're likely fine (see my last paragraph post-edit).

Comment: Pheew. The post-edit kind of went way over my head! =) I think I'll limit my comprehension of it to the term "unlikely" which still means -possible- albeit improbable. =)

Comment: @manu3d Basically, if you're using Entity Framework or another ORM, you should be fine ;)

Comment: What is the correct way to initialize a property of an object that you select without re-creating the whole object? Consider that you join two sequences and you want to initialize a property in obj1 with the complete ob2, whats the best way? You could create a new: `select new Obj1{..., Obj2 = obj2}`, but then you have to initialize also all properties of `Obj1`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'd do that in a foreach loop after the query.

Comment: But that enumerates it twice. In the foreach and later when you consume it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You can always cache it (ie: `ToList()`) ... Assignment is a side effect, and really doesn't make sense in the query itself

Comment: But if you _cache_ it you need two collections. One for the anonymous type holding both linked sequences and one as final result.